# What do these lines on a controller extension mean?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, controller-extension

I'm trying to build a test class for a controller extension on a Visualforce page and I need a more in depth description of what certain lines mean. Help on this would be appreciated.

1)

```
 String msg=e.getMessage();
 integer pos;

 // if its field validation, this will be added to the messages by default
 if (-1==(pos=msg.indexOf('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, ')))
 {
     ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, msg));
 }

 result=false;
```

2)

```
 pr.setRedirect(true);
```

3) The `null` here

```
public void newSkid()
{
   if (updateSkids())
   {
      Skid__c skid=new Skid__c(Name=newSkidName, Dimension__c=newSkidDimension, Number_of_Pieces__c=newSkidNumberofPieces, UOM__c=newskiduom, Weight__c=newskidweight, Bill_of_Lading__c=getBillofLading().id);
      insert skid;

      newSkidName=null;
      newSkidDimension=null;
      newSkidNumberofPieces=null;
      newskidbilloflading=null; 
      newskiduom=null;
      newskidweight=null;
      skids=null;
```

4) The `null!=` here

```
public void deleteSkid()
{
   if (updateSkids())
   {
      if (null!=chosenskidId)
      {
         Skid__c skid=new Skid__c(Id=chosenskidId);
          delete skid;

          skids=null;
          chosenskidId=null;
      }
   }
}
```

5) The `null` statement again here

```
public List<Skid__c> getSkids()
{
   if ( (null!=getBillofLading().id) && (skids == null) )
   {
       skids=[SELECT Id, Name, Bill_of_Lading__c,  
                    Dimension__c, Number_of_Pieces__c, UOM__c, Weight__c
                    FROM Skid__c 
                    WHERE Id =: getBillofLading().id
                    ORDER BY CreatedDate];
```

6) These functions

```
public String getChooserender() {
  if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('p') != null)
    return 'pdf';
  else
    return null;
}

public PageReference deliverAsPDF() {
  PageReference pdf =  Page.Billofladingtest05222013;
  pdf.getParameters().put('p','p');
  return pdf;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When trying to understand some new programming concepts or the specifics of a new language or API, the documentation is invaluable. Here's a couple of resources for you.

- [Force.com Apex Code Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index.htm)
- [Visualforce Developer’s Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index.htm)

Here are some details about the specific code snippets you had questions about.

1) Check out the [Exception](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) documentation for `e.getMessage();`, [String Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm) documentation for `indexOf()`, and [ApexPages](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_apexpages.htm) documentation.

```
 String msg=e.getMessage(); // get the error message
 integer pos;

 // if its field validation, this will be added to the messages by default
 if (-1==(pos=msg.indexOf('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, ')))
 {
     ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, msg));
 }

 result=false;
```

2) [PageReference documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_pagereference.htm)

```
 pr.setRedirect(true);
```

3) The `null` here is assigning "no value" (or a blank value) to all of those variables. I'm not entirely sure what that's doing. It could be resetting the values so that they can be used to insert another skid__c.

```
public void newSkid()
{
   if (updateSkids())
   {
      Skid__c skid=new Skid__c(Name=newSkidName, Dimension__c=newSkidDimension, Number_of_Pieces__c=newSkidNumberofPieces, UOM__c=newskiduom, Weight__c=newskidweight, Bill_of_Lading__c=getBillofLading().id);
      insert skid;

      newSkidName=null;
      newSkidDimension=null;
      newSkidNumberofPieces=null;
      newskidbilloflading=null; 
      newskiduom=null;
      newskidweight=null;
      skids=null;
```

4) The comparison with `null!=` here is checking to see if the `chosenskidId` has a value. It might be better understood as `if(chosenskidId != null)` which is an equivalent statement.

```
public void deleteSkid()
{
   if (updateSkids())
   {
      if (null!=chosenskidId)
      {
         Skid__c skid=new Skid__c(Id=chosenskidId);
          delete skid;

          skids=null;
          chosenskidId=null;
      }
   }
}
```

5) The `null` statement again here is basically saying: If the resulting sObject (or variable) `Id` from the function, `getBillofLading()`, has a value and `skids` is does not have a value, do the following statements between the brackets `{` and `}`.

```
public List<Skid__c> getSkids()
{
   if ( (null!=getBillofLading().id) && (skids == null) )
   {
       skids=[SELECT Id, Name, Bill_of_Lading__c,  
                    Dimension__c, Number_of_Pieces__c, UOM__c, Weight__c
                    FROM Skid__c 
                    WHERE Id =: getBillofLading().id
                    ORDER BY CreatedDate];
```

6) See the inline comments for these functions. Also, check out the [ApexPages](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_apexpages.htm) documentation and the [PageReference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_pagereference.htm) documentation.

```
public String getChooserender() {
  // if the current page has a 'p' QueryString Parameter
  if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('p') != null)
    return 'pdf'; // return 'pdf'
  else
    return null;
}

public PageReference deliverAsPDF() {
  // create a new PageReference to the Page named 'Billofladingtest05222013'
  PageReference pdf = Page.Billofladingtest05222013;
  // add the 'p' QueryString Parameter
  pdf.getParameters().put('p','p');
  // return the PageReference
  return pdf;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, I thought I'd just add a comment... The part about what "null" is described quite well on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming) I'd avoid the usage of the word "blank" when describing null values. Some people think of blank as "" or 0. Instead, it literally means "there is no value (it is void of meaning)," or more figuratively, "the value is unknown."

Comment: Thx; updated removing the "blank" terminology.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, will check on those. I'm just not sure with the usage of 'null' in those expressions.